# Centos BIND9 multiple NS with different IPS

Tags: bind, centos6, nameserver

I just acquired a Root Server and configured OpenVZ for multiple containers. Each container has a different IP. What I am trying to do is to centralize all DNS related stuff in the main server os ( CentOS ).

I installed bind9 in CentOS and configured to name servers for it, which worked fine. Then I tried to add more name servers for each different IP. So what I am trying to do is:

```
ns1.domain.tld 86400 IN A 176.x.x.x
ns2.domain.tld 86400 IN A 176.y.y.y
ns3.domain.tld 86400 IN A 176.z.z.z
```

Then when I add the nameserver ns2.domain.tld to a certain domain, it should point to 176.y.y.y .

My current config is :

```
$TTL 10800
@ IN SOA ns1.palianos.ro.    postmaster.palianos.ro. (
    2014051300  ;serial
    21600    ;refresh after 6 hours
    3600    ;retry after 1 hour
    604800   ;expire after 1 week
    86400 )    ;minimum TTL of 1 day
@    3600    IN    A    176.9.26.140
mail    86400    IN    A    176.9.26.140
ns1    172800    IN    A    176.9.26.140
ns2    172800    IN    A    176.9.26.140
ns3 172800  IN  A   176.9.26.155
ns4 172800  IN  A   176.9.26.155
ns5 172800  IN  A   176.9.109.43
ns6 172800  IN  A   176.9.109.43
ns7 172800  IN  A   176.9.109.44
ns8 172800  IN  A   176.9.109.44
gitlab  178000  IN  NS  ns3.palianos.ro.
gitlab  178000  IN  NS  ns4.palianos.ro.
www    3600    IN    CNAME   @
@    86400    IN    MX    10  mail.palianos.ro.
@    172800    IN    NS    ns1.palianos.ro.
@    172800    IN    NS    ns2.palianos.ro.
```

When I try to dig the subdomain test.domain.tld it gives me no ANSWER SECTION. It works fine for domain.tld tho.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are prepared not to redact the domain name in question, we can probably give you better answers.

Comment: There is no trace of `test` in the zone data included in the question. That would seem like the obvious reason why you get nothing when you try to look up `test`. Also, I don't understand the overall goal of what you are doing. You say that you want to centralize all DNS related stuff to the main host, yet you "add more name servers for each different IP" (which appears to mean just adding `A` records with  `nsX` as the name), what is the purpose of this? Also, why do you have two `nsX` names for each IP? Fwiw, `ns8.palianos.ro` does resolve, if that is the goal (not clear from the question).

Answer (score 0):

The problem at the moment appears to be that the two nameservers (well, one, really; `ns3` and `ns4` have the same IP address) to which you have delegated `gitlab.palianos.ro` aren't responding to any kind of requests about it:

```
[me@risby ~]$ dig any gitlab.palianos.ro @ns3.palianos.ro

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-P2-RedHat-9.9.4-12.P2.fc20 <<>> any gitlab.palianos.ro @ns3.palianos.ro
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
[me@risby ~]$ dig any gitlab.palianos.ro @ns4.palianos.ro

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-P2-RedHat-9.9.4-12.P2.fc20 <<>> any gitlab.palianos.ro @ns4.palianos.ro
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

This means that although the nameservers for `palianos.ro` are happy to provide those delegating records:

```
[me@risby ~]$ dig ns gitlab.palianos.ro @ns1.palianos.ro
[...]
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gitlab.palianos.ro.        IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
gitlab.palianos.ro. 178000  IN  NS  ns3.palianos.ro.
gitlab.palianos.ro. 178000  IN  NS  ns4.palianos.ro.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns3.palianos.ro.    172800  IN  A   176.9.26.155
ns4.palianos.ro.    172800  IN  A   176.9.26.155
```

when I do a more general query and let the recursion sort itself out, I get no answer:

```
[me@risby ~]$ dig ns gitlab.palianos.ro

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-P2-RedHat-9.9.4-12.P2.fc20 <<>> ns gitlab.palianos.ro
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 3480
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gitlab.palianos.ro.        IN  NS

;; Query time: 192 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri May 16 07:09:01 BST 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47
```

I think you need to fix `ns3` and `ns4`, and get them to serve the subzone, before any of this is going to work.